# Where does Homebrew Cask install Applications?

Tags: homebrew, ngrok, homebrew-cask

I used Homebrew Cask to install ngrok.  The installation went fine.  I'm trying to edit ngrok's   config.yml    file.  I can't find it on my mac.

It appears that  ngrok lives here:

```
 /usr/local/Caskroom/ngrok/2.1.3,4VmDzA7iaHb
```

and there is a sub-directory in the above directory, but I can't open that directory.  Any ideas on where I can find  ngrok's  config.yml  file greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default `config.yml` doesn’t get installed. Instead `ngrok` checks `$HOME/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml`.

So on MacOS, for user `foo`, then `ngrok` looks for the file in `Users/foo/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml`.